# Can You Save the Current State of a Vue Model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with `vue.js` and I'm wondering if I can save the **amount** as input via buttons, so that when a user comes back to the pen, they can see what the current number recording is.

Essentially I just want the virtual **DOM** to stay updated with the current number, but I don't know how to go about this.

My code:

```js
var vm = new Vue ({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    amount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    addOne: function(){
      this.amount++;
    },
    subtractOne: function(){
      this.amount--;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
<h2>Amount of Red Cars I Saw Today</h2>
    <p id="times">{{amount}}</p>
    <button id="plus-one" @click.prevent="addOne">Add One</button>
    <button id="minus-one" @click.prevent="subtractOne">Subtract One</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

If you want feel free to fork the pen here: https://codepen.io/anicaise/pen/vRRaoB

Comment: You can save the number into localStorage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Local Storage will only work for the same browser / user.  In order for any kind of state to be preserved, it is going to have to be stored to some form of database.

Comment: Yes, it seems you have to save the current number at backend, then retrieve it when page load.

Comment: @Sphinx okay so there's no way to do it without using a database?

Comment: @database is not required, even you can save the number in one text file at backend.

Comment: Isn't using the localStorage enough? The number is saved in the current browser. If you want it to work across multiple browsers, there's, as said, no other way than using a backend of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you are attempting both you and others would have to be connecting to the same data somewhere.  So unfortunately, without contacting and some outside source to store your updates you will be unable to do what you are trying above.

The two main solution for your problem would be saving to a database or saving to a file.  Without a backend the easiest solution would be to use one of the many API based database services where you can pull and push data to one repository so everyone visiting your site will get and set the same data.

My favorite is [firebase](https://firebase.google.com) because they have a free option so you can play around with it.

And here is an article on [how to get it set up with Vue.js](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-2-firebase-e4b2479e35a8).